# Reg xml output in RestEasy

Tags: rest, jaxb, resteasy

I am trying to get an XML output from a restEasy service. And its working fine. The problem is i am not able to see elements which dont have any values.
I used @xmlElement in domain class wherever necessary. In Json response, i can see elements with null values.This is not working with XML. For Example:

JSON Response:
"chemStructure": {
        "inchi": null,
        "inchiKey": null,
        "smiles": null,
        "iupac": null,
        "imageUri": null,
        "notation": null
    }

XML Response:

I want to see atleast the elemenst with empty tags

Comment: XMLResponse:<chemStructure />

Answer (score 0):

By default JAXB (which is the default binding layer for JAX-RS implementations such as RESTEasy) will not marshal null values.  You can change this behaviour by specifying the `nillable` setting on `@XmlElement`.

```java
@XmlElement(nillable=true)
private String imageUri;
```

Then a `null` value will be represented in XML with the `xsi:nil` attribute.

```xml
<imageUri xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html